# NSURLConnection returning zero length data

Tags: objective-c, ios, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I had async NSURLConnections working just fine when I was using my viewController as the delegate, have all sorts of connections now and I want to do them all through a singleton Connection object. So I'm having Connection create a new delegate object for each connection it makes. Connection is instantiated in the app delegate, but the `+(void)send:(Message *)` function probably terminates.

My feeling about how this works is that the delegate listeners get put in the run loop (I'm not totally clear on this but I think they're not in separate threads. Shouldn't matter because the delegates allocate their own responseData memory.) and the connectionDidFinishLoading executes just fine, but with an empty responseData. By that I mean I find myself in connectionDidFinishLoading but responseData has zero bytes.

Code creating the app delegate (in the send method) is:

```
ConnectionDelegate *delegate = [[ConnectionDelegate alloc] init];
NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate];
```

So my question is two folded:

1. Is the problem that the send method terminates? The delegate pointer has local scope.
2. If that's the problem, what can I do to keep the delegate alive?

Answer (score 0):

You should double check your delegate's implementation of `connection:didReceiveData:`

Remember that you are responsible for collecting the incoming data segments there.

Please read Apple's doc(, especially URL loading system programming guide) and sample code again if any doubt.

Comment: `connection:didReceiveData:` is `[responseData appendData:data]` which I think is pretty standard.

Comment: Then please paste your `connection:didReceiveResponse:` code in your question. Please edit your QUESTION not the comment.

Comment: ok, ZhangChn, I'm new to StackOverflow, sorry. I appreciate your help, though.